# LetsEncrypt certbot gives authorization failed 404 but the validation file exists

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to request a certificate for my website using LetsEncrypt. So I did:

```
docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD"/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt certbot/certbot certonly --manual -d yourdomain.com
```

Then I get an error:

```
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: manual). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: yourdomain.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 2a01:7c*******f:feb8:1cae: Invalid response from http://yourdomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/dY_t**********PbmOrhH668mU: 404
```

My webserver is up and running! And when I request that same url using curl it all works well

```
$ curl http://yourdomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/dY_tTYlo88******OrhH668mU
dY_tTYlo88ZrcXCkM8uGL*******OMlOBp7dMgBs7d0epjyo
```

I tested with curl on the same server and others, they all succeeded.

So, is there any good explanation why Certbot failed?

Comment: It might be that Letencrypt uses IPv6 as is explained [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/getting-404-from-authorization-request-but-can-curl-file-during-debug-challenges/75827). I'm going to test this!

Comment: You should see a log entry for the failed request in your server logs. What does that look like?

Comment: These logs files don't say much. But I can confirm that LetEncrypt will hit your server using IPv6 if you have an AAAA record in je DNS. My case that AAAA record was wrong (pointing to an old server)